# List, string into a integer

Tags: python, string, datetime

I'm trying to split a date and turning it into an integer. Can i still do it if I put my code in the following way? 
`birthdate = '10/08/78'` `bmonth, bday, byear = birthdate.split('/')`

Comment: Um........ yes?

Comment: If you replace `birthday` with `birthdate` then yes (or vice-versa)--just keep the variable names consistent.

Comment: my mistake its suppose to be `bmonth, bday, byear = birthdate.split('/')`

Comment: Why don't you click run and find out?

Answer (score 1):

Ideal way to achieve this is via using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module as:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date = datetime.strptime('10/08/78', '%m/%d/%y')
>>> date.month, date.day, date.year
(10, 8, 1978)
#        ^ Returns complete year
```

But if you just want extract it from the string in the format it is mentioned. You may do it the way you mentioned.

```
>>> month, day, year = '10/08/78'.split('/')
>>> month, day, year
('10', '08', '78')
#             ^ you get as it is value
```

Comment: BTW: you can use just `%x` as the `strptime` format if `locale` is `en_US`

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not create integers. Your `bmonth, bday, byear` variables will hold string values.

To get an integers you need to use next code:

```
birthdate = '10/08/78'
birthdate_split = list()
for item in birthdate.split('/'):
    birthdate_split.append(int(item))
bmonth, bday, byear = birthdate_split
```

Comment: do you know of a shorter way than doing` bmonth = int(bmonth)
    bday = int(bday)
    byear = int(byear)`

Comment: `bmonth, bday, byear = map(int, birthdate.split('/'))` but see @MoinuddinQuadri answer using `datetime` - that is the best way.

Comment: I would like to use datetime but I have to to it this way

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
date=datetime.strptime('10/08/1978', '%m/%d/%Y')
date.month
```